# jQuery - How to make another li be active using the same name of child

Tags: jquery, html, css

There are my codes which HTML,CSS and jQuery Function. Here, I want to create a function that if click items,it will add class active to current clicked. In same time, I'm also want to addclass to another li which has same span name.
 
The example : 
if I'm click "Topic : Test",  "Topic :Test2" also be active in same time. 
*The condition I used same span name

HTML

```
<li class="items">
    <span name="01">
      Topic : Test       
    </span>
 <li>  
<li class="items">
    <span name="01">
      Topic : Test2       
    </span>
 <li>

<li class="items">
    <span name="02">
      Topic : Test3       
    </span>
 <li>
<li class="items">
    <span name="02">
      Topic : Test4       
    </span>
 <li>
```

CSS

```
.active{
   background:blue;
   color:#fff;
}
```

jQuery function

```
 $(function(){
    $('items').click(function(){
      $('this').addClass(active);
      var getName = $('this').find('span').attr('name');
      var getParent = $('[name="'+getName+'"]').parent('.items').addClass('.active');
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$('.items')`, not `$('items')`. Also `$('this')` is incorrect and you must use `$(this)` instead.
Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.items').click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("active");
      var getName = $(this).find('span').attr('name');
     $('span[name='+getName+']').parent().addClass("active");
  });    
});
```

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3bykghL/1/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.items').click(function(){
     $(this).addClass('active');
       var getName = $(this).find('span').attr('name');
       $('span[name='+getName+']').parent().addClass("active");
  });  
});



 <ul>
            <li class="items">
                <span class="name1" name="01">
                  Topic : Test       
                </span>
             <li>  
            <li class="items">
                <span class="name1" name="01">
                  Topic : Test2       
                </span>
             <li>

            <li class="items">
                <span class="name2" name="02">
                  Topic : Test3       
                </span>
             <li>
            <li class="items">
                <span class="name2" name="02">
                  Topic : Test4       
                </span>
             <li>
    </ul>

ul > li.active{
   background-color:blue;
   color:#fff;
}
span.active{
   background-color:blue;
   color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Mike86,I'm just want to use name,not class,but it's also useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a alot of syntactic problems, but here is the JQuery code:

```
(function(){
   $('li.items').on('click', function(){
      $(this).addClass('active');
       var spanName = $(this).children('span').attr('name');
       $('span[name="' + spanName + '"]').parent('li.items').addClass('active');
   });
}())
```

Notice that non of you li tags have a closing tag.